# MacOSX App generated on-the-fly on an ubuntu server - code sign

Tags: macos, ubuntu, code-signing

I have a project, where a JAR is bundled in a MacOS X APP on-the-fly (each time a json file changes in JAR, so I also need to generate the JAR on-the-fly and bundle every time the JAR in the APP). This is done on an Ubuntu server. 
But I also want to code-sign the APP.
Is that possible and if yes, how?

Comment: Can't you just have the JSON external to the JAR, and just read it in when needed?

Comment: I wanted, but unfortunately its not possible.